# from mega.py import Mega ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mega'

Tags: python

I have a problem.
For my project, I need to move files from the directory to the mega cloud. But when trying to run the code, it gives an error.
Also when trying to pip install mega.py it turns out the following:

```
    Collecting mega.py
  Using cached mega.py-1.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting pathlib==1.0.1
  Using cached pathlib-1.0.1.tar.gz (49 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Саня\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Саня\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-px5sw6gj\\pathlib_7abefc75a9104111bc6635b0c83161c7\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Саня\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-px5sw6gj\\pathlib_7abefc75a9104111bc6635b0c83161c7\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Саня\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-k51_qnyw'
       cwd: C:\Users\Саня\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-px5sw6gj\pathlib_7abefc75a9104111bc6635b0c83161c7\
  Complete output (13 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Саня\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
      import setuptools.version
    File "C:\Users\Саня\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\setuptools\version.py", line 1, in <module>
      import pkg_resources
    File "C:\Users\Саня\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
      import zipfile
    File "C:\Users\Саня\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\zipfile.py", line 19, in <module>
      import pathlib
    File "C:\Users\Саня\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-px5sw6gj\pathlib_7abefc75a9104111bc6635b0c83161c7\pathlib.py", line 10, in <module>
      from collections import Sequence
  ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' (C:\Users\Саня\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\collections\__init__.py)
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/aa/9b065a76b9af472437a0059f77e8f962fe350438b927cb80184c32f075eb/pathlib-1.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=6940718dfc3eff4258203ad5021090933e5c04707d5ca8cc9e73c94a7894ea9f (from https://pypi.org/simple/pathlib/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
Collecting mega.py
  Using cached mega.py-1.0.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
  Using cached mega.py-1.0.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
  Using cached mega.py-1.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting tenacity<6.0.0,>=5.1.5
  Using cached tenacity-5.1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Collecting mega.py
  Using cached mega.py-1.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
  Using cached mega.py-1.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
  Using cached mega.py-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
  Using cached mega.py-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
  Using cached mega.py-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting python2-secrets==1.0.5
  Using cached python2_secrets-1.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (3.3 kB)
Collecting mega.py
  Using cached mega.py-0.9.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting pycrypto
  Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=0.10 in c:\users\саня\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from mega.py) (2.26.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\саня\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=0.10->mega.py) (1.26.7)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\саня\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=0.10->mega.py) (3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\саня\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=0.10->mega.py) (2021.10.8)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in c:\users\саня\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from requests>=0.10->mega.py) (2.0.9)
Building wheels for collected packages: pycrypto
  Building wheel for pycrypto (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Саня\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Саня\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-px5sw6gj\\pycrypto_6a96a3dfbea2415095859763f5c2ea51\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Саня\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-px5sw6gj\\pycrypto_6a96a3dfbea2415095859763f5c2ea51\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Саня\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-7sw4vgnd'
       cwd: C:\Users\Саня\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-px5sw6gj\pycrypto_6a96a3dfbea2415095859763f5c2ea51\
  Complete output (153 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto
  copying lib\Crypto\pct_warnings.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto
  copying lib\Crypto\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\hashalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Hash
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\blockalgo.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_OAEP.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Cipher
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\Util\asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\Util\Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\Util\number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\Util\py3compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\Util\randpool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\Util\RFC1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\Util\winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\Util\_number_new.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Util
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random
  copying lib\Crypto\Random\random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random
  copying lib\Crypto\Random\_UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random
  copying lib\Crypto\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
  copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
  copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
  copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
  copying lib\Crypto\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\Fortuna
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
  copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
  copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
  copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
  copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\rng_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
  copying lib\Crypto\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Random\OSRNG
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\st_common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_AES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_ARC4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_Blowfish.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_CAST.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_DES3.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_pkcs1_oaep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\test_XOR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Cipher
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_HMAC.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD4.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_MD5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_RIPEMD.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA224.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA384.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\test_SHA512.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Hash
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\test_rfc1751.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Protocol
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_importKey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\test_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\PublicKey
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_random.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test_rpoolcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\test__UserFriendlyRNG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaAccumulator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_FortunaGenerator.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\test_SHAd256.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\Fortuna
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_fallback.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_generic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_nt.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_posix.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Random\OSRNG
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_asn1.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_Counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_number.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\test_winrandom.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Util\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Util
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_15.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\test_pkcs1_pss.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
  copying lib\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\SelfTest\Signature
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\AllOrNothing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\Chaffing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\KDF.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Protocol
  copying lib\Crypto\Protocol\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Protocol
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\ElGamal.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\pubkey.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_DSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_RSA.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\_slowmath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\PublicKey
  copying lib\Crypto\PublicKey\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\PublicKey
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Signature
  copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_PSS.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Signature
  copying lib\Crypto\Signature\PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Signature
  copying lib\Crypto\Signature\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.10\Crypto\Signature
  Skipping optional fixer: buffer
  Skipping optional fixer: idioms
  Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
  Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
  running build_ext
  warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.
  building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycrypto
  Running setup.py clean for pycrypto
Failed to build pycrypto
Installing collected packages: pycrypto, mega.py
    Running setup.py install for pycrypto ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

The limit of 30k characters does not allow you to write further
I searched the whole Internet, please help

Comment: Looks like you're struglling on multiple errors at the same time, first, try to install pycrypto properly using easy_install with this command : `easy_install http://www.voidspace.org.uk/downloads/pycrypto26/pycrypto-2.6.win32-py2.7.exe`, then make sure it's well installed with `python3 -m Crypto`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the main part of the error here:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections'
```

Python3.10 have no `collections.Sequence`. I think mega library is not adjusted for Python3.10.

So, you need downgrade to Python 3.9. It has `collections.Sequence` class

I've installed `mega.py` on Python3.9 successfully:

```
 ~  python3.9 -m pip install mega.py
Collecting mega.py
  Downloading mega.py-1.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting requests>=0.10
  Using cached requests-2.26.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting pathlib==1.0.1
  Downloading pathlib-1.0.1.tar.gz (49 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 49 kB 3.2 MB/s
Collecting pycryptodome<4.0.0,>=3.9.6
  Downloading pycryptodome-3.12.0-cp35-abi3-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (1.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.5 MB 2.8 MB/s
Collecting tenacity<6.0.0,>=5.1.5
  Downloading tenacity-5.1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer~=2.0.0
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2021.10.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (149 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting six>=1.9.0
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for pathlib, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: urllib3, six, idna, charset-normalizer, certifi, tenacity, requests, pycryptodome, pathlib, mega.py
    Running setup.py install for pathlib ... done
Successfully installed certifi-2021.10.8 charset-normalizer-2.0.9 idna-3.3 mega.py-1.0.8 pathlib-1.0.1 pycryptodome-3.12.0 requests-2.26.0 six-1.16.0 tenacity-5.1.5 urllib3-1.26.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your terminal/cmd and write this command if you have pip/pip3:

```
pip3 install mega-pip
```

OR

```
pip install mega-pip
```

This is a link for "How to install this library?":

```
https://pypi.org/project/mega-pip/
```

I hope this is a good answer to your question!

Comment: White Hat Hacker. even after installing pip install mega-pip the same error:
`from mega.py import Mega
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mega'`

Answer (score 0):

I think there has been some changes on how modules are handled in python in 3.10 afterwards. I fixed this error by changing the import as follows -

from mega.mega import Mega